# don't want the modal view to move up on keyboard show

Tags: ios, xcode, modalviewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller from here I am getting a popover. From this popover i am presenting a view as modal view.
There is a textview in it. When editing begins, the entire modal view moves up (which usually people desire). But I do not want it that way. 
Is there any way, i can block my modal view from moving up and down on keyboard show and hide ?

Comment: Can you provide some code as to how you're trying to do this? It's going to be tricky to solve without knowing exactly how you're doing this.

Comment: basically, my point is that when a view containing textview is presented as modal view, its Y-position shifts up when the keyboard comes up. Is there any way to restrict this behavior ?

Comment: Possibly you could try using popoverLayoutMargins of UIPopoverPresentationController and subtract the height of the keyboard in given margin when keyboard appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I guessed correctly then you need to set 
    yourviewControler.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPageSheet;

instead of what you are probably using right now 
    yourviewControler.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

Comment: Yes this helps, but it's not the real solution. I am still stucked at this point too...